# show recently viewed products for non-logged in users wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm showing recently viewed products for logged in users with below code, of course before this I'm updating user meta in wp_footer action:

```
$rv = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'recently_viewed', true);
```

But I need to show recently viewed products even when user is not logged in. Is there any way to do it with get_option()/update_option() or in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to show recently viewed product list for non-logged in users with cookies. I added below code in my functions.php file and in single product page I'm getting ID values from cookie and using get_post() function to show information:

```
function rv_products_non_logged_in(){ 
    $rv_posts = array();
    if ( is_singular('product-items') && !is_user_logged_in()){
        if(isset($_COOKIE['rv_products']) && $_COOKIE['rv_products']!=''){ 
            $rv_posts =  unserialize($_COOKIE['rv_products']);
            if (! is_array($rv_posts)) {
                $rv_posts = array(get_the_ID());
            }else{
                $rv_posts = array_diff($rv_posts, array(get_the_ID()));
                array_unshift($rv_posts,get_the_ID());
            }   
        }else{
            $rv_posts = array(get_the_ID());
        }
        setcookie( 'rv_products', serialize($rv_posts) ,time() + ( DAY_IN_SECONDS * 31 ),'/');
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'rv_products_non_logged_in');
```

I hope this will help someone else!